# How to render multiselect picklists as checkboxes on a visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I want to Implement multi-select drop down in salesforce through Visual force page. I want to display my drop down like this Please find below scrren shot :

[image: Multi-select dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jquery to add the list in this:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" doctype="html-5.0">
  <head lang="en">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
  </head>
    <body>  
        <apex:form >
            <select id="countries" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="UK">UK</option>
            </select>       
            <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#countries').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Reference: http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-using-jQuery.aspx